# fcitx process using more memory

Tags: ram, onscreen-keyboard, fcitx

yesterday i activated onscreen keyboard after notified fcitx process use 2600 Mb of ram so my machine is super slow,but  everything is ok when i kill that process,what is this fcxti process and what are the solution for this problem. this was happening since yesterday
[image: system moniter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also happening to me and it is really annoying.

Fcitx is, like ibus, is a keyboard input method system. You can go to gnome-language-selector to see which one you're using. In most cases ibus may be enough and it does no harm to remove fcitx completely.

However I need fcitx but I haven't find a way to deal with that. But at least I answered part of your question.